# HTML/Javascript track touch events when finger doesn't move but element does

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web app that is being loaded on a mobile device. It currently tracks finger position on a html canvas using touchmove (which works great). However, what doesn't work currently is when my finger is still, but my canvas itself is moving I can't find a way to track my finger's new x,y coordinates relative to the center of the canvas. Is there any way to do this nicely?

Thanks,
Aaron.

Comment: can you show what you have so far.

Comment: How about storing the last detected finger position and updating that relative to your canvas movement?

Comment: @le_m The problem is I cannot track my canvas movement, so it would be ideal if I could in some way extract my finger position at any time (not necessarily using an event).